# Multiple InfoPath forms (views) for viewing list item details

Tags: infopath, custom-list

I've created and published a custom form using InfoPath. In my custom list on SharePoint 2010, clicking on any item brings up the details window with certain fields.

[image: The ribbon, when I bring up a record's details]

However, in order to see the fields displayed the way my custom form has them, I've got to click **Edit Item** first.

[image: After clicking Edit Item button, the ribbon shows me my different views.]

[image: While in Edit mode, the view I created in InfoPath (entitled Blueprint Validation) is visible. If I get out of Edit mode, I no longer have the option to change views.]

Any way I can let the user toggle between the default view and my custom form's view while in read-only mode?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot, it would be helpful to see what is actually visible  and on the basis of that we can create a links which will redirect it to your info-path view in read-only mode.

Comment: Added screenshots... does that help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should add navigation buttons to your form via Buttons or Picture Buttons, Then add the rule

```
Switch to view: ViewName
```

By doing so you do not need to click the edit button on the ribbon to change views.

[image: InfoPathButtons]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button on your display form and click on manage rules add a rule on selecting actions and select the rule as switch views. Please check the screen shots

[image]